# new ssd wont show in disk management

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, desktop-computer, computer-building, disk-management

I recently bought a new [Kingston 120GB 2.5" SSD (SA400S37/120)](https://www.kingston.com/us/ssd/consumer/sa400s37), to add to my motherboard, an [Asus - H81M-K Micro ATX](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/H81MK/specifications/) ([hardware manual](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1150/H81M-K/E8601_H81M-K.pdf)) with two 6G SATA-III ports (yellow) and two 3G SATA ports (dark brown).

When I boot into Windows 10 from my 1 TB HDD on one of my two (yellow) 6G SATA-III ports, the new Kingston SSD connected to another, 3G SATA port (brown) does not show in Windows Explorer. I tried initializing it in the disk management software but it doesn't appear.

It shows in Device Manager, and when i go into the BIOS Setup. [diskpart](https://ss64.com/nt/diskpart.html) in the console doesn't show the Kingston drive.

My friend said I had to set the drive to a slave drive, but I cannot find that in the BIOS of my motherboard, an [Asus - H81M-K](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/H81MK/specifications/).

EDIT: Yes, it shows an SSD, but I forgot to mention I already have a M.2 SSD which is plugged into a SSD-to-SATA adapter, connected to the other yellow 6G SATA port. The Kingston 2.5" SSD I'm trying to install doesn't appear; it is connected to one of the (brown) SATA 3G ports.

EDIT: i realized that my m.2 and 1tb HDD are connected to the yellow ports on my motherboard so what i have done is swap the m.2 to the brown port and plug the SSD into the yellow port, i have just booted back into windows with the same results, i managed to document everything with screenshots so i will post them now.

[image: device manager]
[image: windows explorer]
[image: bios screenshot]
[image: Disk Management]
[image: disk util after boot]

Comment: Good test. Try it, and let's find out. Also suggest you delete the Comments you made above; do you see how I added their data into the original question with [edit]? This board has _limited_ room for comments, which is why I delete mine once you answer.

Comment: "The Kingston 2.5" SSD I'm trying to install doesn't appear; it is connected to one of the (brown) SATA 3G ports." - This sounds like a case where only a certain amount of SATA ports can be used.  Check your motherboard manual for any such limitation.

Comment: https://amazon.com/Lycom-DT-120-PCIe-Adapter-Support/dp/B00MYCQP38 and similar devices let you move the M.2 off the yellow 6GB/s port. Since you only have two of those, such a card may be helpful.

Comment: i have added some photos and explained more in the edit part of my post